# add page title to javascript code

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript snippet which passes an id and the reffering page to a php page where i then collect the ip address, what i wanted to do is also capture the page meta title and also forward that to the php page. However i am very new to javascript and not sure if it is possible.

Any suggestions would be appreciated below is my javascript code, thanks.

```
var track = new Image();
track.src="http://testsite.co.uk/~vtrack/track/track.php?id=801003&self=" +   document.referrer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
track.src = "http://testsite.co.uk/~vtrack/track/track.php?id=801003" +
            "&self=" + document.referrer +
            "&pageTitle=" + document.title;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.title = `Your Title goes here`
```